# Repeat use of Scanner.hasNextLine()

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

During one of my assignment i was trying to read a file and print it line by line. I tried to use the hasNextLine again and it didn't work. I tried to complete it somehow but i want to know if there is some way i can go through my file all again without creating a new Scanner.

here is my code snippet

```
sc = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {

            System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
        }
```

I want to use the while again later but i cant do that. Is there a way to reset or bring it back to the top and traverse through the file again.

Comment: have you thought of creating a method like "`readFile(File file)`" which you pass the file you want to read to and inside that method u create a scanner and print the files contents, then close the scanner... you can then simply call that method when you need it

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a new `Scanner` after closing the first one:

```
sc.close();
sc = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));

// do the same thing again
```

Comment: the whole point is to not create a new scanner i want to use the same one again. I can do that easily which is what i did eventually but i found that as a bad idea and was thinking of an alternative to it.

Comment: @sohil It's not a bad idea. Why do you say that?

Comment: because you keep creating new objects and thats not good for the memory

Comment: @sohil The old scanner will be garbage collected. There are no memory issues here.

Comment: @sohil This is a well documented fact. There's really no question about it.

Comment: I am sorry i am new to JAVA i am not really into memory much so i am trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

To optimize, you can save reference to file for future use.

```
File f = new File(args[0]);
sc = new Scanner(f);
//...
sc = new Scanner(f);
```

Scanner is anything but smart iterator, so cost of creating new can be smaller than 'rewinding' old one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `FileReader` decorating a `RandomAccessFile`:

```
RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(args[0], "r");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileReader(f.getFD()));

//Read through scanner

//Rewind file
f.seek(0L);

//Read through file again
```